# Query entity by oneToMany relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some trouble with filtering an Entity with a OneToMany relation.
The goal is to get all Events that are related to specific units by its unit ids
I wanted to keep the entities simple so i removed a few properties.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT * from event WHERE event.sourceid ~ 'someid' (AND unitids IN (22,33,44)?)
```

**UnitEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "UnitEntity")
@Table(name = "Unit")
public class UnitEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Nullable
        private Long id;   
}
```

**EventEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "EventEntity")
@Table(name = "Event")
public class EventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Nullable
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UnitEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UnitEntity> units = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Edit:
Seems to work with a query like this (tested with pgadmin)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from event 
INNER JOIN event_unit eventunit ON (event.id = eventunit.event_id)
AND unit_id IN (1,3)
```

But when i try to build this query with hibernate i get the following error:

> Path expected for join!

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider learning Hibernate and HQL before trying to solve real issues. The HQL query for this would be:

```
select distinct e
from Event e
join e.units u
where u.id in :unitIds
```

or more efficient

```
select e
from Event e
where exists (
  select 1
  from e.units u
  where u.id in :unitIds
)
```